# popen handle across persistent connections

Tags: php, popen

I am trying to execute a command by using `popen` and then print out its progress via AJAX. I have found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333664/simple-long-polling-example-code) extremely helpful and got the AJAX to script exchange working fine. The problem is that every time there is an async GET to `test` from ajax, the handle on `popen` is repeated. If I have the shell only run once, then the handle is no longer valid. I can't figure out how to make $handle be persistent accross requests.

```
public function test()
{
      chdir('my dir');
      $handle = popen('make install 2>&1','r');
      echo fread($handle, 2096);


}
```

There will only be one user requesting this at a time....only used on the Admin back end of things. The output from AJAX is always, "Making install in src".

Comment: It's not really the `popen` handle you need to keep open, it's the PHP script itself you need to keep running. Are you doing this in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do that. You'll have to run the 'make install' process in the background (e.g. via `exec()`) and redirect it's output to a file/pipe that you can read from when executing the AJAX requests.